# How to save outlook office 365 email body in SharePoint Online Document Library using Microsoft Flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, incoming-email, flow

I am trying to save Office 365 Outlook emails in SharePoint Online Document Library when any new email arrives.

Here I am sharing my flow

[image]

When I receive new email with attachment and when I go to flow history I get following response.

[image]

When I click on the flow details I get the following screen

[image]

It means that the last action skipped.

I am not able to get any idea what may be the wrong in the configuration.

If you have any idea then please share.

Answer (score 5):

This has been a matter discussed in Microsoft's Power Users Community within several threads. A concluding topic, [save an email to a document library](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/save-an-email-to-a-document-library/td-p/10351), sheds some light for how you may actually succeed with your requirement.

As using Flow's functionality to re-attach email's attachments to a new file seemingly just does not work, you can achieve the same results by using the Flow's **Parserr** (https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/shared_parserr/parserr/). Parserr's primary function is to allow you to extract data from recurring incoming emails and email attachments.

**Disclaimer**: According to [Parserr's own web site](https://parserr.com/), their tools have also the billable versions besides the Free version. The Free version has some strict limitations with e.g. max 10 documents/mail attachments per month. I'm not associated with this product in any manner.

Parserr has a ready template to be used with SharePoint in here: [Extract data from a new email and create a new item in SharePoint](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/80c999203f3d11e7b9809da41e7af698/extract-data-from-a-new-email-and-create-a-new-item-in-sharepoint/). This template, according to the site, has been used only 22 times as of today, and is a notably new addition, so not too much existing documentation will be available to assist on how the template shall be used.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. I will be back after looking into options you provided. :-)

Comment: It's now possible to extract email using "Export Email" action.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Plumsail Actions](https://plumsail.com/actions/) to do this. This is [the instruction](https://plumsail.com/docs/actions/v1.x/flow/how-tos/convert-email-to-pdf.html).

The example fo Flow:

[image]

Note: This is a paid solution and I'm a member of

Answer (score 1):

You can now extract email using "Export Email" action and easily save the file to a SharePoint library.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Flow-Ideas/Ability-to-extract-email-as-MSG-or-EML-file-from-various-Flow/idi-p/23166

[image]