# Save whole email in SharePoint library as .eml file using MS Flow and open it outlook

Tags: flow

I want to save the O365 email (whole email itself) to SharePoint (online) document library as a .eml file and open up in office outlook.

I have followed the approach given in this url: 
[How to save outlook office 365 email body in SharePoint Online Document Library using Microsoft Flow?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/221094/how-to-save-outlook-office-365-email-body-in-sharepoint-online-document-library)

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Flow-Discussion/Save-email-to-Sharepoint-document-library-full-email/m-p/4440/highlight/true#M995
https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/outlook-connector-more/
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Flow-Discussion/Save-email-to-Sharepoint-document-library-full-email/m-p/4440/highlight/true

I have found that the email gets saved in the library, but when I open it from the library (downloading from lirabry using outlook), the file opens but shows no any content (white email screen). The extension of the file is .eml. Can anybody suggest, how can i open this email in outlook with content?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Since I am forcibly changing the extension, probably content are lost. Note sure. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Save it as .msg extension instead of .eml and it should load with content.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/87509)

Comment: @DikeshGandhi you are wrong. This is a clear workaround solution suggested by the answerer. Please stop incorrect flagging.

Comment: Thanks @Deepmala, I have tried that .msg and .eml before posting here. Unfortunately no luck!

Answer (score 0):

We were able to utilize the Outlook Action "Export Email" to capture the body content of the Email and then in the "Create File" action using the body content from the Export Email action as the File Content.

This created the `.eml` file in SharePoint and when clicked contained the content from the email Body.

I did not test this with a `.msg` extension.

Answer (score 0):

Add another action "Export Email" between these two steps and get the "Message Id". Remove the body in "Create file" and add it again.

[image]